# how to assign current logined user to a models object in django

Tags: python, django

i have a user , who will create a company profile.The user is created by the django's django.contrib.auth.models.  so the problem is to assign the currently logined user to the company profile's user.
my models.py is:

```
class Company_Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  logo = models.ImageField(_('Company Logo'), upload_to='image', null=True, blank=True)
  address = models.TextField(_('Contact Address'), max_length=50)
  phone_no = models.IntegerField(_('Contact No'), max_length=12)
```

my forms.py is:

```
class Company_Prof(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Company_Profile
    fields = ('logo','address','phone_no')
```

my view for company profile is:

```
@login_required()
def company_prof(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    comp_prof = Company_Prof(request.POST or None)
    comp_prof.user = User.objects.get(username=request.user) 
    if comp_prof.is_valid():
        save_prof = comp_prof.save(commit=False)
        save_prof.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Thank you for Registration')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('company/'+str(save_prof.id))
else:
    comp_prof =Company_Prof()
variables = RequestContext(request, {
    'comp_form': Company_Prof()})
return render_to_response("comp_profile.html",
                          locals(),
                          context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: One, saving an object with commit=False will create the object, but will not COMMIT it to the database until save with commit =True is called. Therefore, your object is available for modification between these two lines.

Two: The current user object is available in your request as 'user'. Calling request.user will return the user object.

So for your case, you need to assign the user object before calling save again, like this:

```
save_prof = comp_prof.save(commit=False)
save_prof.user = request.user
save_prof.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> comp_prof.user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
> ```

Incorrect. [`request.user` is already a `User`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

```
comp_prof.user = request.user
```